# Visual Studio Code unbound breakpoint Node JS React TypeScript

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code

When I try to put a breakpoint and start debugging, the breakpoint becomes hollow and unbound.

Does someone know how to fix this problem? I've already looked around and tried and nothing helped so far...

I'm using **VSCODE NODEJS REACT TYPESCRIPT**

#### launch.json

[image: launch.json]

#### tsconfig.json

[image: tsconfig.json]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it by opening the terminal first, "npm start" then pressing F5 to start debugging.

Comment: Cannot do it  in my case because I don't have node in my local computer but on the docker image running the react app.

Comment: @PlayingWithBI found a solution? I'm in the same situation

Answer (score 3):

Setting sourceMap to true in tsConfig.json solved the issue.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "sourceMap": true
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just had the same problem on an open source project. I tried several things, like updating the VSCode, "sourceMap" was already true, but nothing helped.

Then I realised that there were discrepancies in launch.json: While the whole project was working on the "dist" directory, launch.json was working on "out".

[image]

Now it works as expected.
Of course I will create a pull request.